Shell Command options not appearing on VScode
VScode window
As you guys can see, the ">Shell Command:" options are not appearing on VScode. And, in turn, the code. command is not working on git bash.
I have tried quite a few number of things as mentioned in the answers of similar questions like:

Uninstalling and reinstalling both of them and checking their initial settings in the wizard
before pressing install.
Checking environment variables to make sure that a valid path exists.
Making sure that git is enabled in VScode.
And a few more things. None of them seem to work.


have you tried restarting your pc ?

Click on "Terminal" on VScode and then select "New Terminal" when it opens you can choose PowerShell
